# How to find AbstractDiagram object of IDiagramCustomizer in Modelio 3.7.1

Tags: java, modelio

I implement IDiagramCustomizer interface in my class for customizing diagram palette. But i dont get AbstractDiagram of this customizer calling for. How to access to diagram object via IDiagramCustomizer

I need to access diagram properties for customizing palette tool

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing IDiagramCustomizer, you have to override several methods including:

1. keepBasePalette() which will allow you to specfifc if you want to keep the defined palette on the extended diagram type
2. fillPalette(PaletteRoot paletteRoot) which will allow to define a set of palette groups composed of a set of Tool.

Comment: Yes i override this functions.This functions customize the palette but is there any way to access AbstractDiagram element. I mean i want to use diagram element that owns this palette